# oracle replace subcharacter using REGEXP_REPLACE function

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I have the following column values in my table called TEST and want to replace these values like this:

> XX01 -> XX1
>
> XX02 -> XX2
>
> XX03 -> XX3
>
> XX04 -> XX4
>
> XX01/ABC -> XX1/ABC

which actual mean, I want to remove the 0 by replacing it with an empty string.

I already used the oracle REPLACE function like this (other situation):

> REPLACE(column_name,'0', '')

but for this situation this will not work, since I have other values, that contain 0, but must not be changed.

How can I replace the zeros in an appropriate way using reg expressions in oracle?

I hope you get my point and sorry for the bad formatting.

cheers

Comment: Post the other values too, since regexp_replace needs pattern.

Comment: only and exact these values (XX01, XX02, XX03, XX04 and XX01/ABC), the remaining values must not be changed.

Comment: the other values are arbitrary, but do not starts with XX.

Comment: It would be better if you at least post one row.

Comment: A02 or A48/11 for example, just one or two characters followed by one or two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
regexp_replace(yourValue,'(XX)0([0-4])(*)', '\1\2\3')
```

It will works for all the case you specified... It will only replace the 0 if it is followed by another number as it is in the case you have. If you have a 0 not followed by a number then it won't be replaced.

Not sure if it is exactly what you want as you did not tell us what the "other 0 values that are not allowed" looks like..

Comment: can I just use '(XX)0(0-4)+(*)', '') too? The characater muss starts with XX.

Comment: can you please explain me why you use '\1\2\3'?

Comment: @curious It is to print the grouping statement (1-2-3)